# Mysql: How to properly use and index the date time field in mysql where clause?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

We have listings table where we keep all our products. The products have expiry determined by column "ExpiryDate" in the listings table. We want to get all the listings that have expired a day before:

**Previous query:**

```
SELECT * from listings
WHERE DATE(ExpiryDate + interval 1 day) = DATE(now());
```

**Modified query:**

```
SELECT * from listings
WHERE ExpiryDate between DATE_FORMAT(now()- interval 1 day, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') and DATE_FORMAT(now() -interval 1 day, '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59');
```

I read it somewhere that in "previous query", we can't use indexing on datetime while we can leverage indexing optimization in the "modified query". Is that correct? And is the "modified query" best tuned for performance if we put indexing on column "ExpiryDate"?

Comment: First query `Add 1 day to every record, then check if it's the same as now()` - you can't use indexes because you're modifying the stored value. Had you written it in a different way - `Check if the date is same as (now() minus 1 day)` then MySQL can use indexes since it will calculate which number `now() - 1 day` corresponds to and can use it as comparison base, which is exactly what the second query does. It does not modify the `ExpiryDate` before comparing it to a value. It modifies the  **VALUE** it compares `ExpiryDate` against.

Comment: Is the query you're using tuned? You have `EXPLAIN`, `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` and [profiling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profile.html) available which you can use for measuring. If your `ExpiryDate` is a `datetime` and if it's indexed, then you should be fine. If it's still slow, it's time to tune the hardware, what resources are available to MySQL (look up `innodb_buffer_pool_size`) etc.

Answer (score 2):

The basic rule is to **avoid hiding an indexed column in a function call**.  In your "previous" query it is both `DATE()` and also `+ INTERVAL`, which is effectively a function call.

Also, several simplifications can be made to say "did it expire *yesterday*":

```
WHERE ExpiryDate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND ExpiryDate  < CURDATE()
```

And you need `INDEX(ExpiryDate)`.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` is generally important, and should be about 70% of *available* RAM.  However, the buffer_pool is probably big enough.  Profiling rarely says anything actionable.